# Visual Basic 6 check if dll exists

Tags: dll, vb6, detect, basic

I am in need of a little help, I'm trying to exit sub, if a test.dll is detected (test.dll is just an example), and if the dll does not exist, just continue to do the other things in the code. I'm trying to do it like this, however even when the dll exists, the sub doesn't exist. Can you tell me where I am wrong? Any advice? I am leaving an example below.

```
Private Declare Function GetModuleHandle Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetModuleHandleA" (ByVal lpModuleName As String) As Long
```

```
Sub main()
    If GetModuleHandle("test.dll") = 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Do other things
    End if
End sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer CristiFati, from what i see GetModuleHandle always return - null.

I found this:

"The GetModuleHandle function returns either NULL (0) if the dll cannot be found, or a Windows HANDLE if it is found. So comparing it with the value 1 is unlikely to work. You should compare it not equal to zero."

The problem here is, i don't have good skills in visual basic 6, so i don't know how to exactly to include in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally file existence check is done by querying the file system for file's attributes.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetFileAttributes Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetFileAttributesA" (ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()
    If FileExists("test.dll") Then
        MsgBox "DLL exists", vbExclamation
    Else
        '--- do other things
    End If
End Sub

Public Function FileExists(sFile As String) As Boolean
    If GetFileAttributes(sFile) = -1 Then ' INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES
        FileExists = (Err.LastDllError = 32) ' ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION
    Else
        FileExists = True
    End If
End Function
```

Accessing the attributes is (used to be) optimized in various network providers so this performed very well on network shares.

Using `Dir` to check for file existence might mess up with your current directory enumeration process. Generally `Dir` function in VB6 runtime is a very bad example of using global state for local operation -- never a good design pattern.

Answer (score 2):

According to: [[MS.Docs]: GetModuleHandleA function (libloaderapi.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandlea) (**emphasis** is mine):

> Retrieves a module handle for the specified module. **The module must have been loaded by the calling process**.

So:

1. *GetModuleHandle* is not the right way, as the *.dll* should already be loaded into the process for it to succeed (and its existence on disk would be irrelevant)
2. Even if it was the right way, the condition (`= 1`) is incorrect. Function returns (positive) handle values (the chance for such a value to be *1* is extremely slim), or *NULL* (*0*) if the *.dll* wasn't loaded

There are number of variants on [[VBForums]: Classic VB - How can I check if a file exists?](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?349990-Classic-VB-How-can-I-check-if-a-file-exists) for example, taking the 1<sup>st</sup> (and simplest) one:

```
If Dir("test.dll") <> "" Then
    Exit sub
```

Beware, the ***.dll* path is important**!!!

Comment: The problem is, the "dll" is activated only when i run specific program, at other times it is inactive.

Comment: A *.dll* can't be "activated", that's nonsense. From your question I understood that you want to check whether it exists on disk. Is that the case? If not, the question is not well formed, and you should edit it, **clearly specifying** what you want. [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).